# I don't see the environment in VSCode after MiniForge installation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda-forge, mini-forge

I have installed Miniforge + VSCode on my (new) PC but when I launch VsCode and try to select a kernel, I can't find the Base environment. How to get it and the different environment I created with conda

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). I believe you'll need to select an environment **before** selecting a Jupyter kernel (which BTW is covered here: [Manage Jupyter Kernels in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-kernel-management)).

Answer (score 0):

Click on kernel in the top right corner to make your selection.

[image]

You can choose an existing python environment. You can also create a new virtual environment.

[image]